# what am i doing wrong with this array and foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have two arrays, where I can get from using $result[0] or $result[1].

I've done a `print_r($results[0])` and a `print_r($result[1])`. they both give me the two different arrays which I want.

However, I'm not able to get any of my information if I do this

```
foreach($results[0] as $result){
    echo $result['data']['id'];
}
```

I want to be able to differentiate the two arrays, so I want to be able to get information from the two.

I have done a json_decode on $results as well.

If someone can help me out here, that'll be great! thanks

EDIT:

```
Array
(
    [nonsense] => Array
        (
            [more] => information
            [less] => less stuff
        )


    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => some id
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [eh] => some eh
                )
        )
)

Array
(
    [more stuff] => Array
        (
            [more] => information
            [less] => less stuff
        )


    [more data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [freshstuff] => some id
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: i think you might want to display the results of your array ?

Comment: Maby you could show this two arrays structure?

Comment: `print_r($result[0])` and `foreach($results[0]..` result**s** or result? Maybe typo?

Comment: I've added the array and i've corrected the results issue. Thanks

Comment: [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) is more useful than `print_r`, as it results in a PHP parseable representation of the array.

Comment: @outis: I've been coding and debugging PHP for quite some time and somehow completely overlooked `var_export`. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: @outis it works better using <pre></pre> all the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `$result['data']['id']` doesn't exist. `id` is inside yet *another* array.

`foreach` is not useful in this situation because the data isn’t uniform. When you loop through `$results[0]` you get the `nonsense` key on the first iteration and the `data` key on the second iteration. Furthermore, the `nonsense` key is an array of key/value pairs, while the `data` key is an array of arrays of key/value pairs.

`$results[0]` and `$results[1]` *seem* uniform, but they contain different keys.

```php
echo $results[0]['data'][0]['id'], "<br>\n";
echo $results[0]['data'][1]['eh'], "<br>\n";

echo $results[1]['more data'][0]['freshstuff'], "<br>\n";
```

**Update**

foreach() doesn’t work with this kind of array. [array_walk_recurisive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is generally a good choice in this situation.

```
<pre>
<?php

$results = array(
  array(
    'nonsense' => array(
      'more' => 'information',
      'less' => 'less stuff'
    ),


    'data' => array(
      array('id' => 'some id'),
      array('eh' => 'some eh')
    )
  ),

  array(
    'more stuff' => array(
      'more' => 'information',
      'less' => 'less stuff'
    ),


    'more data' => array(
      array('freshstuff' => 'some id'))

  )
);


function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key: $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($results, 'test_print');

?>
</pre>
```

displays

```
more: information
less: less stuff
id: some id
eh: some eh
more: information
less: less stuff
freshstuff: some id
```

Depending on your needs, you may also find some of the other [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) useful.

Comment: So I'm not able to do a foreach to iterate all the data? I dont want to be typing [0]... [1].... [2].... and so forth If I remove [0] from the foreach, I'm able to get outputs

Comment: The example code for [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) will get you to the inner most data in `$results`. It prints `more holds information`, `less holds less stuff`, `id holds some id`, etc. You might also investigate the other [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to see if they're useful for your purposes. I don't know enough about your data or intent to offer more than that.

Comment: I'm just trying to use a foreach loop. is this even possible?

Comment: In my example, it works if I dont have the [0] in my foreach. a multi curl set up and another one with just two curls. But I'm using multi curl, and I get two arrays. Thats why I'm trying to only use foreach to get the first array, but my attempt of [0] doesn't work

Comment: For example if I do `foreach($results as $result){echo $result['nonsense']['more']; it'll give me a value, but it will give me an error for the second array, because I'm iterating both arrays. Thats why I'm trying to only iterate through the first array which my attempt of using [0]

Comment: `foreach($results[0] as $result)` will make `$result = $results[0]['nonsense']` on the first iteration, where you can `echo $result['more'];`. On the second iteration $result becomes `$result = $results[0]['data']` and `echo $result['more'];` is an error because `$results[0]['data']['more']` **doesn't exist**. I understand what you're trying to do, but you can't use a `foreach` loop to do it. That's why I suggested looking at other array functions, particularly  [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Comment: I see. Yiks so this is the only way huh? I'm probably going to have to create tons of functions if I want to get certain values throughout my page?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/168341) to me. The problem with using `foreach` in this scenario, is the way your array is structured. Consider re-examining your problem with that in mind and posting a different question.